# Large scale matrix multiplication using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am facing a problem where I need to perform matrix multiplication between two large matrix `A [400000 x 70000]` and `B [70000 x 1000]`. The two matrices are dense and have no special structure that I can utilize.

Currently my implementation is to divide `A` into multiple chunks of rows, say, `sub_A [2000 x 70000]` and perfrom `sub_A * B`. I noticed that there are a lot of time is spent on I/O, i.e. read in the `sub_A`. Read in the matrix takes about 500 seconds and computation takes about 300 seconds.

Will using PyTables here be useful to improve the I/O efficiency? Are there any library that will help in improving the time efficiency?

Here is the code:

```
def sim_phe_g(geno, betas, chunk_size):
    num_indv = geno.row_count
    num_snps = geno.col_count
    num_settings = betas.shape[1]

    phe_g = np.zeros([num_indv, num_settings])
    # divide individuals into chunks
    for i in range(0, num_indv, chunk_size):
        sub_geno = geno[i : i + chunk_size, :]
        sub_geno = sub_geno.read().val
        phe_g[i : i + chunk_size, :] = np.dot(sub_geno, betas)
    return phe_g
```

`geno` is of size `[400000 x 70000]` and `betas` is of size `[70000 x 1000]`. `geno` here is a large matrix that is stored in disk. The statement `sub_geno = sub_geno.read().val` will load a chunk of the genotype into the memory. And this statement costs a lot of time.

Also, I divide the big matrix into chunks because of 32GB memory size limitation.

Comment: the timings seems large to me. Show your current code, to see, if it could be optimized.

Comment: @Daniel I have attached my current code.

Comment: Assuming you have the memory for it, you may be able to move `geno` to a RAM disk.  That should greatly reduce the I/O time of the computation.

Comment: Why not divide matrices into submatrices(instead of rows) to increase re-use ratio of all datas so comm is not an issue anymore? Why not multiple divide-conquer levels until you reach 100x100 size? If this is not good enough, try strassen's multiplication which decreases data by 1/8 for each level of divide/conquer.

Answer (score -1):

If applicable try using tensorflow for large matrices multiplication, as you can see from this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-vs-tensorflow-speed-on-matrix-calculations-9cbff6b3ce04) that tensorflow performs significantly better in case of large matrices under many circumstances. The reason for the same most likely being that its primarily built for this very purpose of handling large matrices efficiently.

for more details on the specific use of matrix multiplication kindly refer to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul).

I tested it on a (1000,1000) matrix for multiplication:

for `numpy.matmul` = **60 ms ± 5.35**

for `tensorflow.matmul` = **42.5 ms ± 2.47 m**

100 runs for each were conducted sharing mean and stdev

**P.S. Tensorflow's cpu version was only used**

Comment: will using CPU version of Tensorflow benefit the matrix multiplication here?

Comment: If you have access to a GPU, using tensorflow and GPU will vastly reduce the computation time.

Answer (score -2):

Try using TensowFlow for GPU optimization, it's very good for matrix multiplication as it will allow you to parallelize each operation.

Comment: This should be a comment.